# something grab html in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

here's my problem, i have html file with many tables, tr, and td. i already get specific value from specific field with DOM . but i want get all the value without make to many if condition like what i do, because every table have different position field td. i want just get value after **Dimension:** so although every table have different position field td can get the value. can u give solution like use regex to get specific value. how if 100 tables and the **Dimension:** td position in different position it make to many if condition. i hope u get what i say. sorry my english. here's my code and output below. this one just a bit of the code.

Table:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<TABLE class="tab1" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="">
<TR>
<TH align=left colspan=2 bgcolor=#0066CC><H1> &nbsp;Start RIP Job</H1>
</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;Printer:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;RunJiang Flora 3204P&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;File:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;8iG6e8r5T.png&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>

<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;Dimensions:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;39.2 x 38.8cm&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Another Table:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<TABLE class="tab1" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="">
<TR>
<TH align=left colspan=2 bgcolor=#0066CC><H1> &nbsp;Start Printing</H1>
</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;Printer:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;RunJiang &nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;File:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;8.png&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
 <TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;Resolution:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;39.2 x 38.8cm&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TH align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;Dimension:
</TH>
<TD class="td1" align=left> &nbsp; &nbsp;29.2 x 28.8cm&nbsp; &nbsp;
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

CODE :

```
$source=file_get_contents("C://xampp/htdocs/Champion/machine-
logs/LogCampusHTML/CPSITES.HTML");
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($source);
$rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName("table");
 $a = "Start RIP Job.....";
 $length = strlen($a);
 $b = "Start Printing.....";
 $length1 = strlen($b);

foreach ($rows as $ala) {
$pjg = $ala->getElementsByTagName("td");
    $tes = $pjg->length;
    $rs = $head->length;
    $ben = $ala->getElementsByTagName('th')->item(0)->textContent;
    $length2 = strlen($ben);

$satu=  $ala->getElementsByTagName('th')->item(0)->textContent;
$dua= $ala->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->textContent;
$tiga= $ala->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(1)->textContent;

if($length2 == $length){
$empat= $ala->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(4)->textContent;
}else if($length2 == $length1){
$empat= $ala->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(3)->textContent;
 }
}
echo $dua;
echo $tiga;
echo $empat;
```

OUTPUT :

RunJiang Flora

8iG6e8r5T.png

39.2 x 38.8cm

RunJiang

8.png

29.2 x 28.8cm

Comment: you can set for loop. like for($i=0; $i > 100; $i++){ // in your tr code }

Comment: u don't get what i say, my english bad. the point is how i get value RunJiang Flora after Printer: with another solution. without  $ala->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->textContent;

Comment: because if 2 tables and field Printer: in different position, i should make it to if condition. how about 5 tables and field Printer: in 0,1,5,6.. u get it ?

Comment: i already add another table to make understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XPath allows you to pick out content relative to other content wherever it is in the document.  So no loops or ifs...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$source=file_get_contents("NewFile.html");
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($source);
print_r($dom);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$textList = $xp->query("//th[contains(text(),'Printer')]/../td/text()");
foreach ( $textList as $text )  {
    echo "Text=".$text->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

This code retrieves the data after the Printer label.  The XPath looks for a `<th>` tag with text that has Printer in it, it then goes back a level (to the `<tr>`) and then on to the `<td>` field and returns the text.

The same logic can be applied to any other th/td combination.  Although it does assume that the data is in the only td tag in that tr, but if this is the case it should do.

Edit:
To limit the number of loops and group data together, an alternative approach would be...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$source=file_get_contents("NewFile.html");
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($source);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$textList = $xp->query("//table[//th[contains(text(),'Printer:')]]");
foreach ( $textList as $text )  {
    $printer = $xp->evaluate(
            "string(descendant::tr[th[contains(text(),'Printer')]]/td/text())",
            $text);
    echo "printer=".$printer.PHP_EOL;
    $dimension = $xp->evaluate(
            "string(descendant::tr[th[contains(text(),'Dimensions')]]/td/text())",
            $text);
    echo "Dimensions=".$dimension.PHP_EOL;
}
```

This just does a loop for each table which has a "Printer" element in it, the for each table it extracts the values for each field your after.

Comment: it works, but the value just one from 2 table. it should be 2.

Comment: Sorry - just updated the code, it will work with as many entries as there are.  Just have to get a list of the nodes rather than just the one.

Comment: it work's. but how if i want get another field. it to many foreach right ? if i want get dimension i should foreach again ?

Comment: Another approach can be used for grouping data like that - see updated code.

Comment: it work's. but sorry again. how if another table don't have Printer: field. in my case another table Printer: have name is Device name:

Comment: Using `//table[//th[contains(text(),'Printer:') or contains(text(),"Device")]]` would find any table with either label - and you can add to it if you want.  You will have to fetch the data as above for each option.

Comment: can u help me again ?, i tried get value in <h1> tag, Start Printing. this the code i try but not work.
$head = $xp->evaluate(
              "string(descendant::tr:H1/text())",
              $text);
      echo "head=".$head.PHP_EOL."<br>";

Comment: You probably want tr/h1 (for some reason it seems to convert all tags to lower case)